# How to populate settings with Unity?

Tags: c#, web-config, unity-container, ioc-container, structuremap

I have the following appSettings key-values in a web.config file:

```
<add key="SomeSettings.Received" value="Mottatt"/>    
<add key="SomeSettings.Processing" value="Under behandling"/>
<add key="SomeSettings.Finished" value="Ferdig behandlet"/>
```

I have the following class:

```
public class SomeSettings : IConfigurationSettings
{
    public string Received { get; set; }
    public string Processing { get; set; }
    public string Finished { get; set; }
}
```

In StructureMap the following would populate the SomeSettings class:

```
ForConcreteType<SomeSettings>().Configure
            .EnrichWith(
                (session, original) =>
                session.GetInstance<ISettingsProvider>().PopulateSettings(original)
            );
```

Can I do something similar with Unity without having to make changes in the web.config file?  If so, how?

Comment: `Unity3D` game engine or `Ubuntu Unity`? I guess the former

Comment: Unity as in Microsoft's IoC  http://unity.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Unity does not have such a feature.
But the [TecX project on codeplex](http://tecx.codeplex.com) contains some enhancements for Unity that allow you to do the same thing.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddNewExtension<EnrichmentExtension>();
container.RegisterType<SomeSettings>(new Enrichment<SomeSettings>((original, ctx) =>
  {
    ctx.NewBuildUp<ISettingsProvider>().PopulateSettings(original);
  }));
```